# Reformat an image from png to ico

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

how to reformat an image from png to ico?This code creates a .ico file, but when I open it manually, I get the error "Cannot read this file. This is an incorrect bitmap, or the format is not supported"

```
from PIL import Image

filename = r'git icon.png'
img = Image.open(filename)
img.save('git icon.ico', format='ICO')
```

git icon.png:

[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce without having the png file.

Comment: I tried with a file on my computer, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: are you sure the Image.open call was successful?